# Spring MVC with maven Customer Form web application not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm trying to write a simple web app to get started with Spring.I Don't know where the application was not executing.import this Maven Project code and run in your IDE. Please Help me in Code to run the Project.

Here's what I have:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-crm-rest</display-name> 
  <absolute-ordering /> 
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>list-customers.jsp</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
  <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-crm-rest-demo-servlet.xml</param-value> 
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

main servlet.xml: spring-crm-rest-demo-servlet.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

      <!--  Add support for component scanning --> 
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

      <!--  Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support --> 
      <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

      <!--  Define Spring MVC view resolver --> 
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp" /> 
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
      </bean>

      <!--  Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool --> 
      <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
      <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo_customer_db?" /> 
      <property name="user" value="hbstudent" /> 
      <property name="password" value="hbstudent" />

     <!--  these are connection pool properties for C3P0 --> 
      <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
      <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" /> 
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" /> 
      <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" /> 
      </bean>


  <!--  Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory --> 
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" /> 
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" /> 
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
  </props>
  </property>
  </bean>

  <!--  Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager --> 
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
  </bean>

  <!--  Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations --> 
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

  <!--  Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... --> 
  <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" /> 
  </beans>
```

CustomerController.java

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // need to inject the customer dao
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel)
    {
        // get the customers from dao
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers();

        // add the customer to the model 
        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        return "list-customers";
    }
}
```

Entity class : Customer.java

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customerform")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="father_name")
    private String fatherName;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="dob")
    private String dob;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFatherName() {
        return fatherName;
    }

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerForm [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", fatherName="
                + fatherName + ", gender=" + gender + ", dob=" + dob + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }

}
```

interface:CustomerDAO.java

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;


public interface CustomerDAO {

    public List<Customer> getCustomers();
}
```

CustomerDAO implementation class : CustomerDAOImpl

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    // need to inject the session factory
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // create a query 
        Query<Customer> theQuery =
                currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        // execute query and get result list
        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

        // return the list
        return customers;
    }

}
```

view page : list-customer.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>List Customers</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h2>CRF-Customer Registration Form</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        <!-- add out html table here -->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Father Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Dob</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- loop over and print our customers -->
                <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${customers}">

                    <tr>
                        <td> <c:out value="${tempCustomer.firstName}" /></td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${tempCustomer.lastName}" /></td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${tempCustomer.fatherName}" /></td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${tempCustomer.gender}" /></td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${tempCustomer.dob}" /></td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${tempCustomer.address}" /></td>

                        <%-- <td> ${tempCustomer.lastName} </td>
                        <td> ${tempCustomer.fatherName} </td>
                        <td> ${tempCustomer.gender} </td>
                        <td> ${tempCustomer.dob} </td>
                        <td> ${tempCustomer.address} </td> --%>
                    </tr>


                </c:forEach>

            </table>

        </div>

    </div>      

</body>
</html>
```

Database: MySql Workbench
Table Name : customerform

[image: This is my Database creation structure]

Table Name : pic 2 : customer form

[image: Database table data]

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.luv2code.springdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-crm-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.6</mysql.connector.version>
        <c3po.version>0.9.2.1</c3po.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3po.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2</version> 
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>spring-crm-rest</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Builds a Web Application Archive (WAR) file from the project output 
                and its dependencies. -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Project Structure:

[image: this spring-mvc maven structure]

This is my Console error :

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:564)
```

I'm new to Spring-MVC + Hibrenate and MySql. When run my application browser is not hitting to controller not including list-controller.jsp page.import this Maven Project code and run in your IDE. Please Help me in Code to run the Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in database connection you dont need to use : `?` , and you need to verify the database port if  it is `3306` or not :

```
 <!--  Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool --> 
      <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
      <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo_customer_db" /> 
      <property name="user" value="hbstudent" /> 
      <property name="password" value="hbstudent" />
```

and the last thing you need to be sure if the user `hbstudent` has all user accecs

Comment: hello boss,project is fine haa

Comment: happy for you :)

Comment: this is console:  
Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)

Comment: you ll find my project here , i used almoste same technology ; https://github.com/azzabihaythem/newTest/tree/master/PFE.test01

Comment: try to drop your database and create an empty one

Answer (score 2):

This is Look like Database connect problem:

Try this

```
<!-- declare datasource bean -->  

 <bean id="dataSource"  
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName? 
   useSSL=false"/>  
  <property name="username" value="databaseUsername" />  
  <property name="password" value="databasePassword" />  
 </bean>
```

Here is a project:

https://github.com/imrangthub/BlogSolutionUsingSpringJdbcWithXmlConfig

Comment: hello ,brother not running

Comment: in my console : 

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)

Comment: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'jdbcUrl' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'jdbcUrl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?